# Need help with lms511 drivers on ROS!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cloned these drivers for use `https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/laser_drivers/tree/hydro-devel` for use. But when I do `roslaunch lms5xx.launch` i get this error

```
A Timeout Occurred - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: select() timeout!
```

[lidar/lms5xx-2] process has died [pid 5099, exit code 2, cmd /home/axe/catkin_ws/devel/lib
Please help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249475/need-help-with-lms511-drivers-on-ros!/) by [Aakash](https://answers.ros.org/users/28734/aakash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-01-03**:
You should have updated the question by adding the new errors you are experiencing and not deleting what was there earlier.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-01-03**:
Anyway, the error means that the file descriptor is not ready. Check to see if the device is connected to the right socket and you have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a fairly common error. You have likely not sourced the `setup.bash` from your workspace. This will add the path of your newly cloned package to the ROS path. In general, it does what in catkin terms is called 'overlaying your workspace' to your environment variables.

Go to your workspace directory and run the following command `source devel/setup.bash` (assuming you are using a catkin workspace).

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2016-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aakash](https://answers.ros.org/users/28734/aakash/) on 2016-12-07**:
It worked thanks. But I again ran into an error by running the same command the error is
A Timeout Occurred - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: select() timeout!
[ERROR] [1481114272.357489388]: Initialize failed!
[lidar/lms5xx-2] process has died [pid 5099, exit code 2, cmd /home/axe/catkin_ws/devel/lib

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-12-08**:
This is a different problem. The `select()` call is used for a file descriptor, for an input operation. Do you have the SICK laser connected properly? Maybe the package has a script for testing connection?

**Comment by [Aakash](https://answers.ros.org/users/28734/aakash/) on 2016-12-08**:
@2ROS0 the only two connection I made to the LIDAR are power and lan! I guess that's right...

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-12-08**:
Hmm, I would suggest you update the original question and see if someone else has any ideas.